# jqueryui tabs : is it possible to keep the navigation tabs visible when content is scrolled vertically?

Tags: jquery-ui, navigation, tabs, vertical-scrolling

My jqueryui tab-set consists of several pages of fairly lengthy content -- the user must scroll vertically to move through each document.  Here's a simplified version:

```
 /MAIN TEXT\  /END-NOTES\
 =============================

 blah blah blah
 .
 .
 . (lots more text)
 .
 the end
```

If the user is reading through the main text, and has scrolled down, the navigation tabs scroll out out view. If the user then wishes to consult an end-note, the user must scroll back to the top of the document in order to make the navigation tabs visible so he can click on the END-NOTES tab.  I would like to keep the navigation tabs visible at all times, even when the content is being scrolled vertically, so the nav-tabs appear to "float" at the top of the page.  Is this feasible using the jqueryui tabs plugin?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you could do it by wrapping the tab content `DIV`s with a `DIV` that has a fixed height and have a `overflow: scroll;` style on it.

Comment: Thanks, Gert. It works well, and making each content DIV a fixed height and applying  the overflow: scroll also works.  I appreciate your taking the time to reply. Regards, Tim.