# JQueryUI tabs - content via AJAX scrolling

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am using JQueryUI : content via AJAX and have linked to lengthy pages, with #tabs's div height set to 800px. Yet pages overflow, so I put overflow-y to auto.

Now, tabs scroll with the content, I wish them to be sticky so as to only content scrolls and user sees them if he has scrolled down. I tried, but was unable to find as to how should I display data in certain div after pulling it from remote pages. Please guide.

I checked this ([jQueryUI Tabs - Scroll content only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4427965/jqueryui-tabs-scroll-content-only)) and this ([jqueryui tabs : is it possible to keep the navigation tabs visible when content is scrolled vertically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3123990/jqueryui-tabs-is-it-possible-to-keep-the-navigation-tabs-visible-when-content)) before creating this question, don't find them relevant to my query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using CSS you can set the `tabs` to be fixed. Then set the `content` to have a `margin-top`.

[Here is an example on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ayhP6/1/)